# What manga is this girl shrinking into a child from?

Tags: identification-request

I've found this pretty cute image on the web, and I'm curious as to why the girl turned into a child, and what happens next. I've tried a reverse image search, but it didn't yield any satisfactory results. Does anyone here recognize this image? Could you please tell me where it comes from?

[image]

Comment: Apparently, this manga includes a character named "Nikaidou" (二階堂) and a character named "Touma" (冬馬). Perhaps that will be useful knowledge.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect such a quick response! Thanks, I'll try to find what I can with those. ^^

Comment: If you find the answer don't forget to post it here too.

Comment: Of course I'll do!^^ I'm having no luck so far, though... Anyone got tips on how to perform searches more effectively? I'm searching for the words themselves on Google, but I can't help but think there's a better way...

Comment: http://myanimelist.net/character.php?q=%E4%BA%8C%E9%9A%8E%E5%A0%82 see if any of these match

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that site! I'm checking right now. ^^

Comment: The only two *manga* I can find that have both 二階堂 and 冬馬 are *Honō no Dōkyūji: Dodge Danpei* and *Steal!*. The latter is a *yaoi manga*; the former might fit, but I don't recognize any of these characters from it. (Neither is a very well-known *manga*.) Also, where did you find this image?

Comment: I found it on Visible Time (Yeah, I know, the website's NSFW, but the image isn't, and I'm interested in the manga itself), which didn't have any info on it. I'm also pretty unlucky on my side of the search, as none of the manga I've found so far seem to match this one.

Comment: I was more thinking that there might be some hints on the page by whoever posted it.

Comment: Sadly, the page doesn't show whoever posted it, and the page itself doesn't have any more hints; it's just a plain, detail-less link to that image.

Comment: I've had no luck at all on my side of the search; the closest manga I've found style-wise is AAA, but even that one doesn't quite match. :( Is there really no more clue to be drawn from the basic gist of the dialogue?

Comment: Not really. It talks about not hearing from her dad, being unable to find Nikaido's house, taking Tohma to a hospital, and lastly seeing the girl on the bench, commenting on her baggy clothing, and coming to a realization that the little girl is basically becoming the older woman.

Comment: Shoot, too bad... Thanks to all of you anyway, I'll continue researching on my side. (And to avoid cluttering the comments with extended discussions, I won't post any more comments until I actually find the answer, or at least an actually solid clue; sorry about that).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pages shown in the question comes from the short story **Heart no Kusuri** in the shoujo manga collection [**Majo no Lesson**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=2308) by *Natsumi Matsumoto*.

The two-page spread of *Heart no Kusuri* one-shot:

[image: Heart no Kusuri spread]

And Chinese cover of *Majo no Lesson*:

[image: Chinese cover]

Summary:

> Majo no Lesson is a collection of shoujo short stories including the title short about a girl who is always teased by the boy she likes about having long black hair like a witch. She actually is a witch and her hair holds her power, but she almost cuts it when she inadvertently seals the boy's voice away.

---

<sub>If you're wondering how I found the manga, I split the image in your question into two, then I did a [Reverse Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivGP8fGVh9nbg2D29O15RcH0gCvfcg9iVg3pSDIurVR_1xoccGxyG6BIOoDptnmUUaz5OHDFdgGAJ5EBI-1mbfauCf2Agprf9HIjLTVoP-zbCFsq7lrPAlgcZ2nBcbUqIq3Jh_1V_11recRHk4PSbVRatd5EvXgcdf9Ia2CIWnYx4hOrhjbmoezMzWEB6x7scke5EPmuaiPSuRi0HkfaNJtcUB2AXRutiEwIhKUUxuTnLIhEj0B5VzlkElfvAHp_1xzpL3pPcfgevveljr6TzI0ZqMpsGVl7Z8gfHXuZe2AoK1fvaQhU6HHOBNcvUqH-p2RXMj0y5F7-axqeU5izs-RiRNCeRvFuCKdBEKanqjXQr_15AlD4gV2ht6t3h6aADWyI-1up-KX9o568qm_1I4xKzCUscpUF6GW4IMa8ykA7asvxnws1vpWnbpMExXfCk4qum5KnWCRnwgobshGr8x8evM9djZVaA0ETML8IGN9vUFh8h0FjS0ZTeJ5ewsV-FOgTZxhEv7X1PSCeSaVKcFA6B-sOcAIQeqrFnhLuRwlvkW9mrpE0VjDQV3piWrwQNdW7dMZ2JCV1nTL8LPinGkatWryEA4-ATS66val_1ySWL6Zs_1PbpM7zDv1EHpfoOILfE4JMDqF9pBhU05dmkVzxnNTAnRVmt6xDwLLazHl0NSMnRaO5TiF9GQBOPw3iVJ_1_1ACms58dNwkQbZ2r2P_1g-o87yOJqbrAmShZsEJdYpJ99lpo8Pt-jNRg9Fp53ANPETkL8yxPoLo5CogcknqhjViqC0xp3QDb9zBx3Vn_1fbCpICzLk9FnA62OxkqrIlWDK094Q5y7xTEjLpZv294q0nfsCVWvs9ViatV6e8WsAE-mPnc2a4zzAaOr7Pf3T8dU-Ukuz7TfBZlQP94-Lf4RhzgNJ9oQ6cU-aIVmYUEaR_171e_1uLFF5llsbGMRCZRBSpXanyKLHa1SeqWFrDfaeOHeHcVEdrfce2d-gBAeD0rUtPC3gIOBl3xf8YrqMSP3-VTWDb8-Fr6Zur9jbCwz1McfVTqPtkOTFWS2uKrdtdSJE8TiN0seiuiWvXEGQEdyKrZBq4X4zuGAHzVgaFNz9tWGxTox3ReEyg9Dt4Us9XUQJv7c84R3nyRx03dzkL4UkmKFmh9_1O8l4jlUz0UrM0-p4_1T7Ii3kSx6xuGvS78Ei56R2yAB0Ht4idsvxzUS09EQCc24trW3KjL1UaV113hX8arHvnIEeZS2LOC9_1MUVOEz4mJ3oNHNAvrMhHxl04Dz-1G30TuWc9Q8S4cKzHP6TSc9E24PvSu6LC_1AMSwd2d3VytC1JzM0IldiRyx2PFFAq4V9hKY1ffvfXVNwuSbILo4PdemcuXnoQlWs4DNY4S_1DRza3DTdh7_18gM_10UW2IEaUVlOj7_1nAPUzeQb1qufwkyqLx9Evr6NIWyiB-LdUfMhmjIgHd5x-CW4uigikAcqhCuLbZzX-1WbPNYDVXtENDchc5AUbpyy5Dwu-75xkUFKPiWz2ogKcv0_1UHRz0VV9N-WYx2awuND4GE), which led me to [this](http://club.history.sina.com.cn/thread-1827659-5-9.html) page. I did an Image Search once again using the cover page. Voila!</sub>

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! That looks interesting and cute, I'll check that one out! ^^